# What does it mean to call a VB class method with two sets of parentheses and the Of keyword?

Tags: vb.net, syntax, function-declaration, function-definition

There's a method call (which I have anonymized) in a VB class I'm looking at that's like the following:

```
Dim variableName As ClassName = methodName(Of ClassName)(someOtherArg)
```

The definition of the method in another file starts with the following:

```
Protected Function methodName(Of ClassName As {SuperClassName, New})(someOtherArg As someOtherClassName) As ClassName
```

Generic names aside, what is this syntax doing? It seems like two arguments are being passed to the `methodName` method, but the first one has a variable type or something (some sort of polymorphism perhaps?).

Basically, I'm just trying to figure out what this VB syntax is doing, and I've had no luck Googling things like "VB function definition with Of keyword", etc. Thanks.

Comment: [Generic Types in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Of` indicates a generic type or a generic procedure.  These are discussed in detail in the F1 help, under *Visual Basic / Visual Basic Language Features / Data Types in Visual Basic / Generic Types in Visual Basic* and *... / Generic Procedures in Visual Basic*.

Comment: Thank you. The following article did help better explain it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-procedures. I still find the syntax a bit tricky, but maybe that's just because I'm not totally familiar with VB yet. Thanks.

Comment: @HartleySan The equivalent syntax in C# would use greater-than / less-than symbols (or angle brackets if you prefer) e.g. `MethodName<ClassName>(someOtherArg)`.

Comment: That does help, Craig. Thanks.